# glob() is successfully identifying files, but I get a "404" when trying to access them?

Tags: php, directory, lamp, glob

My local LAMP environment is using AMPPS for apache. My project directory is structured like so:

```
public/
    index.php
    css/
    js/
    img/
        layout/
            banners/
                banner1.jpg
                banner2.jpg
                banner3.jpg
src/
    config.php
    library/
    templates/
        header.php
        footer.php
        nav.php
```

inside **header.php** I have the following code:

```
  <ul class="slideshow">
    <?php
        $images = glob( $GLOBALS["config"]["paths"]["images"]["layout"] . "/banners/*.jpg" );
        foreach($images as $image){
          $out = "<li><img alt='banner' width=1280 height=320 src='".$image."'/>ASC Online</li>";
          ChromePHP::log($out);
          echo $out;
        }
    ?>
  </ul>
```

( the global $config is set in the `src/config.php` file. )

When the code is echoed out, it appears to be correct:

```
<li><img alt='banner' width=1280 height=320 src='/Users/Tom/Web/dev/asconline.local/public/img/layout/banners/banner1.jpg'/>ASC Online</li> 
<li><img alt='banner' width=1280 height=320 src='/Users/Tom/Web/dev/asconline.local/public/img/layout/banners/banner2.jpg'/>ASC Online</li> 
<li><img alt='banner' width=1280 height=320 src='/Users/Tom/Web/dev/asconline.local/public/img/layout/banners/banner3.jpg'/>ASC Online</li>
```

If I go to the URL indicated in the output above, the image files are there... The directory is correct.

However, in-browser, I am getting a **404: File Not Found** when the browser tries to retrieve the files.

It is not permissions because I am able to get other files/images in the project dir.

Any ideas?

Comment: HTML image tag is from the web root (relative to `/Users/Tom/Web/dev/asconline.local/public/`; glob returns the filename from the filesystem root

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `glob` is returning paths relative to the drive root. When accessing through the browser, it is done relative to the *document* root, which is most likely the `public_html` folder.

You will need to do something like:

```
"... src='".substr($image,strlen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']))."' ..."
```

Comment: That was it -- thank you. :) When I move this project from local drive to my server, will I need to readjust this line again or will it more or less be good to go? Thank you for your help.